# Pensiamoci su domani

Tags: prepositions

I have read the following sentence:

> Pensiamoci su domani

Does "su" add anything here or is it just idiomatic? Would "Pensiamoci domani" be wrong/not usual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s idiomatic:

***[Pensarci su, sopra](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/pensare.html)***:

> riflettere con attenzione su qualcosa

(Hoepli)

Comment: AFAIK riflettere = pensare, so the difference between "pensarci su" and "pensarci" in my original question is the "attenzione" ?

Comment: They are about the same in meaning, *su or sopra*  make the sentence a bit more assertive.

Answer (score 1):

*Su* in this sentence means "about this (topic) ". Another equivalent phrase could be *pensiamoci sopra domani* that has the same meaning.

Could it be omitted? Yes, I don't think it is unusual to omit it (on my experience).